# A more efficient way to handle my data and save memory

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, encoding, categorical-data

So I have data from written reviews of hotels.
My idea is to use the words that show up in the review to predict the rating for the review.

My problem is, that when turning these categorical variables to numerical by using dummies, the created dataframe is absolutely massive, and takes up a lot of memory, especially if I try to handle the full data.

An example of my process here:

```
sample_data = {'Review': ["This hotel was really good. I enjoyed it a lot","We enjoyed our stay here a lot","The hotel was a total mess. I hated every second."],
              'Rating': [4,3,1],
              'unique_words':[["this","hotel","was","really","good","enjoyed","lot"],["enjoyed","our","stay","here","lot"],["the","hotel","was","total","mess","hated","every","second"]]
              }

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

dummy = pd.get_dummies(sample_df.unique_words.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
```

This results in this DF:

```
   enjoyed  every  good  hated  here  hotel  lot  mess  our  really  second  \
0        1      0     1      0     0      1    1     0    0       1       0   
1        1      0     0      0     1      0    1     0    1       0       0   
2        0      1     0      1     0      1    0     1    0       0       1   

   stay  the  this  total  was  
0     0    0     1      0    1  
1     1    0     0      0    0  
2     0    1     0      1    1
```

There's one row per review, and a column for every unique_word that shows up.
This allows me to do what I want, and the algorith is atleast somewhat accurate.

The problem is that the actual data contain nearly 20k reviews, and they are quite long.

How could I go about encoding my data in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Use numpy sparse matrix

Comment: You are basically just creating word vectors, consider using: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer

Comment: You could also remove frequent words which do not contribute much like and, or, the, a,... and use stemming to map all words to their word-stem.

Comment: @jottbe There is some filtering of words in handling the real data, like only selecting words that show up enough times and I take out words that have little impact in the scoring. (Even though that process could be heavily improved aswell)

Could you elaborate on what stemming exactly is and if you have any resources to learn it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/stemming-lemmatization-python